# Shall I use both .com and a localised domain or Shall I use .com only?

Tags: seo, domains, web-development, ranking, local-seo

I have a classified website and Now its running on the internet fine. It has a .com domain. In there users can put advertisments to any location by selecting the country and city.

So I also bought a local domain to deploy a site in my country.

The reason why I think it good to go for a localised domain is I beleive that any country's peoples' trust their localised domain.

But when I do that I am not going to use any localised language or any thing.

I am just upload my project from this new domain.

Also my some friends says If my country can select from .com version why you should go to localised domain?

That also make sense.

Also I am worry about SEO thing. What will happen if my country domain get a bigger traffic and then will it appear on top of the results in google? Will my .com domain come 2nd? If some user search for my website will search engines mixed up my domain results? for eg: first link will be from localized domain, Contat us link from .com domain? like wise

So What are your ideas?

What should I do? Shall I stick with .com only or Shall I use my localised domain?

I need a descriptive answer please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target both local and international audience. **.Com** is best option. For SEO preference use Location with Keywords. Example: xyz london, abc paris and etc.

No your .com and .local domain collision to each other in SERP. Please be careful.

Answer (score -1):

For effective localization ,

verify your business in google places or bing places and similar local listing website

Provide address in your website.

Get listed on map.

User location intent in your content like  xyz services in abc(place name).

upload a kml file in your webroot.

Answer (score -2):

.com for international audience and .localised for your country

Comment: I know it. What I am saying is my local audience can also serve from my international site.

Comment: You can provide an option to switch to local site or redirect certain traffic from specific region to your .localized domain